# Binding resize-event to an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i found [this script](https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/blob/master/jquery.flex-images.js)

on line 23/24 is this code:

```
$(window).off('resize.flexImages'+grid.data('flex-t'));
$(window).on('resize.flexImages'+t, function(){ makeGrid(grid, items, o); });
```

what does `resize.flexImages` exactly do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'resize.flexImages'` is just a string that [represents an event type in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) - it's being used in that script to begin the name of the event that is being bound to the event handler function, in this case `function(){ makeGrid(grid, items, o); }` during the `on()` function call.

The `.off()` function call doesn't specify a handler function, as it is presumably already bound/attached to that event during the `on()` call - which again is specified as a string. [The `off()` just removes the handler.](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

If you read the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/on/ you will see jQuery recommends this convention for naming the event so it doesn't interfere with other events, in this example, presumably other [`resize` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify
> removing or triggering the event. For example, "click.myPlugin.simple"
> defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular
> click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be
> removed with .off("click.myPlugin") or .off("click.simple") without
> disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces
> are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one
> name needs to match. Namespaces should contain upper/lowercase letters
> and digits only.

... From the jQuery docs